# Is there a way to check excel sheet has rows null in POI java library?

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I could not find any method to check POI sheet has null rows.
I have tried, Sheet.getLastRowNum(),Sheet.getFirstRowNum(),Sheet.rowIterator(), they all issue NPE.

I am really really confusing right now.

Note: But Sheet object itself is not null though.

```
int numberOfSheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
    Sheet sheet;
    int maxColumnsCount = 0, headerRowIndex = 0;
    Row row;
    Member member;
    List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        //find the maximum cells in a row, it is assumed that max cells container is only valid data. Otherwise Header or Footer.
       //THISE LINE('sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()') GIVE ME NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (maxColumnsCount < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()) {
                maxColumnsCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                headerRowIndex = rowIndex;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (headerRowIndex < rowIndex) {
                member = parseMember(row, memberExcelImportType);
                member.getTownship().setId(townshipId);
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(member.getFullName()))
                    members.add(member);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry, here's the stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(XSSFSheet.java:842)
at com.taraaung.tarabar.tarabarlibs.utility.ImportUtilPOI.readExcelFileUsingPOI(ImportUtilPOI.java:45)
at com.taraaung.tarabar.tarabarlibs.utility.ImportUtils.readExcelFile(ImportUtils.java:32)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.personExportImportUrl.PersonExportImportHttpServe.doPersonImport(PersonExportImportHttpServe.java:153)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.personExportImportUrl.PersonExportImportHttpServe.serve(PersonExportImportHttpServe.java:86)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.MyServer$ValidateSession.serve(MyServer.java:2608)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.MyServer.serve(MyServer.java:770)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:1557)
at com.taraaung.taraserver.server.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:1152)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Umm, just found that the sheet which issues `NPE` is ChartSheet (i.e, it does not have any kind of rows),** then I just check the instance of sheet and skip chart sheets. :D `if (sheet instanceof XSSFChartSheet) {
                continue;
            }`
'Thanks for the help'

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace where `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` throws NPE and `sheet` is not `NULL`.

Comment: If `sheet` object was null, the exception should not be thrown within `XSSFSheet.java`, isn't it? `(XSSFSheet.java:824)` is, `public int getPhysicalNumberOfRows() {
        return this.rows.size();
    }`

Comment: `XSSFSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(XSSFSheet.java:842)` seems to be a **very** old version of `apache poi`. I am not an software archeologist.

Comment: I though that I was using latest version, here is the gradle \n `//POI
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.5-FINAL'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.5-FINAL'`

Comment: [The latest stable release is Apache POI 3.17](https://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: That means 3.5 version is not the latest version?  Thanks I will have a look at the latest one.